# Is it a bug that when @'ing another user that callout is deleted from a comment?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

When attempting to `@` another user, the `@` callout disappeared after I'd submitted. Is this a bug? I also refreshed the page to be sure the comment I was trying to reply to hadn't been deleted.

> Before submit:
>   [image: Before submit]
>
> After submit:
>   [image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This is by design.

From the main meta FAQ [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/278659):

> Note that the author of the post will always be notified of any new comment. You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the @name will be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.

Whether the system *should* work that way is another question. But if you want to discuss that, better take it to main meta - it's a network-wide effect, and won't be changed for an individual site.

Comment: Ninja'd me, again :)

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks!

Comment: >.< My Internet died while posting my answer...